# Move and rename files that have no name extension

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm having problems figuring out how to do this bash script since I'm very new to bash.

I want to grab all the files I have in a directory, change their names (I think the changing names part can be done with `mv`) and move them to another directory (again with `mv`). Problem is that the files do not have an extension. Their names are simply numbers like: `1`, `2`, `3` etc. Just the number. How do I grab each extensionless file, change its name and move it?

Thank you.

Comment: How does your script look?

Comment: You say the current names are `name1`, `name2`, etc. What do you want to change them to? `othername1`, `othername2`? or `name101`, `name102`? Need more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **extended globbing** to search for files with only digits in their names:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in +([0-9]) ; do
    newname=newpath/...    # Build the new name.
    mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use `basename` command to grab filename itself and test it with grep if it has a dot character, which would mean it has extension. That can be used inside if statement, and if it does use `continue` statement to go to next file. As for  moving, that can go after if statement. That way `mv` command is unreachable unless it doesn't have extension